# 2 problemas , acrecentar elementos em array condicionalmente e depois criar outro array com valores por data

Tags: javascript

DO RESULTADO DA CHAMADA A API TENHO ESSE RESULTADO:

```
var origemApi = [
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP' },
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'IDP' },
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'IDP' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP' }
    ]
```

No vue usando groupBy e having consegui esse resultado:

```
var destinoFront = [
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP', total: '10' },
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'IDP', total: '20' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP', total: '30' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP', total: '15' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP', total: '15' }
    ]
```

ou seja, agrupei pelo tipo e a data e chamando SUM consegui gerar o total
Acontece que no índice 3 (data 23-04), so tenho o tipo ADP de total 30 de um total de 30 registros portanto, NÂO TENHO outo índice iDP com total 0 tipo:

```
var destinoFront = [
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP', total: '10' },
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'IDP', total: '20' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP', total: '30' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'IDP', total: '0' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP', total: '15' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP', total: '15' }
    ]
```

preciso talvez com splice empurrar um índice que esteja faltando pois preciso SEMPRE na mesma data ter 2 TIPOS (ADP e IDP) para alimentar ulguns gráficos que necessitam de uma data onde eu tenha dois dados para os eixos x e y.

Acontece que na API de um total de 30 registros, se todos forem ADP(ou vice-versa) o IDP como nao existe naquela data, a consulta nao me retorna IDP 0.
Esse é a parte do problema...

Supondo que eu tenha conseguido isso, agora precisa contaenar os dois tipos em uma única da ta tipo:

```
var primeiroProblemaResolvido = [
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP', total: '10' },
      { data: '23-04', tipo: 'IDP', total: '20' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP', total: '30' },
      { data: '23-05', tipo: 'IDP', total: '0' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP', total: '15' },
      { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP', total: '15' }
    ]

var resultadoFinalEsperado = [
    ['23-04', '10', '20']
    ['23-05', '30', '0']
    ['23-06', '15', '15'] // ou seja, um aaray com a data, o tipo ADP e o tipo IDP(apenas os valores
]
```

Ja tente de tudo usando map e filter com push e splice mas quando resolvo o primeiro problema, o segundo se perde e vice versa.

Comment: Não consigo formatar esse texto corretamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--Edit--**

Fiz uma revisão no código, pois apesar de estar funcionando anteriormente, temo que em algum caso extremo, conhecidos como "edge case", o código possa produzir um resultado inesperado, já que objetos não garantem que serão iterados na mesma ordem que sua propriedades foram adicionadas.

Instancias de `Map` por outro lado garantem essa ordem, portanto utilizei um mapa para tornar a união dos objetos com a mesma data mais fácil.

```js
var problema = [
    { data: '23-04', tipo: 'ADP', total: '10' },
    { data: '23-04', tipo: 'IDP', total: '20' },
    { data: '23-05', tipo: 'ADP', total: '30' },
    { data: '23-06', tipo: 'ADP', total: '15' },
    { data: '23-06', tipo: 'IDP', total: '15' }
]

var solucao = Array.from(problema.reduce((acc, d) => acc.set(d.data, [
    d.data,
    d.tipo === 'ADP' ? d.total : (acc.has(d.data) ? acc.get(d.data)[1] : '0'),
    d.tipo === 'IDP' ? d.total : (acc.has(d.data) ? acc.get(d.data)[2] : '0')
]), new Map()).values());

console.log(solucao);
```

Comment: user 140828 !!!!!!!! meu geniooo, tu é da terra mesmo? kkkk teu código encaixou de forma perfeita!!!!, usei tua segunda solução, achei mais elegante com filter e map, so não entendi o % no filter....mas olha so, você resolveu apenas  o segundo problema, acho que você esqueceu o primeiro problema ou eu não consigui me explicar direito. O primeiro problema ta logo acima onde as vezes um TIPO não vem da API por exemplo de IDP tiver cheio (com 30) o ADP não vem e eu preciso dele com 0 por isso tentei com o splice sem sucesso. olhando do inicio do texto olhe o segundo array.

Comment: @sidiara, fiz uma revisão no código.

Comment: Meu querido.....Deus te abençoe e que Ele cuide desse seu raciocínio. Quem pensa com precisão e lógica tem uma fonte de riquezas. Meu muito obrigada! Salvou meu final de semana e 3 meses estudando ES